# how to read the AverageRecordSize in dbcc showcontig

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In another question I've read the answer that I can use this statement 
`dbcc showcontig ('profile') with tableresults`
to show the size of a record in a table

Now I see this column:
`AverageRecordSize`

and the docs say this:
`Average record size in that level of the index or whole heap.`

2 questions I have:

1 Is the 'record size' in bytes?

2 Can I use this value to get an indication for the database size?

Say if this value says 1000 and I have 1000 records, my database will have a (data-)size of 1MB?

I am delivering a database and the client asks how large the initial database must be. So I thought I'd calculate the size for a few months work of records this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats** function instead of deprecated dbcc showcontig. It will give you average and max row size. After the this you can calculate overall database size.

Comment: And does this work:? "Can I use this value to get an indication for the database size?
Say if this value says 1000 and I have 1000 records, my database will have a (data-)size of 1MB?"

Comment: You can go by table vise. and find out database size. `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (DB_ID(N'DBNAME'), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table_name'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'); `

Comment: Thanks. What I meant to ask was: can I just multiply the average record size by the number of records (for all tables) and that will approx be my database size? Or is there so much overhead in storing data that 2300 bytes will take an extra 10% or so on disk?

Comment: Yes, it will give you approx size. Also you have to consider indexes. +10% :)